# Show that the set $K = \{n^k : n,k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is countably infinte

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Show that the set $K = \{n^k : n,k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is countably infinte.

---

The set $K$ is countably infinite when there exists a bijection between it and the natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow K$, and it is bijective. It suffices to show that $f$ is bijective if it has an inverse $f^{-1}$. Let $g:  K\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be that particular inverse. Let $q\in \mathbb{N}$ and $r \in K$.

We have that $f(q) = q^k$. Assume $g(r) = r^{\frac{1}{k}}$$(**)$. In order to show that $g$ is in fact the inverse of $f$ we must show, $f \circ g = 1_{K}$ and $g \circ f = 1_{\mathbb{N}}$.

$(f \circ g)(r) = (f \circ g(r))= f(r^{\frac{1}{k}}) = r$

$(g \circ f)(q) = (g \circ f(q))= g(q^k) = q$

We have that $g$ is in fact the inverse of $f$, and hence, $f$ is a bijection. Therefore, the set $K$ is countably infinite. $\square$

---

This is what I have as a proof. Would you take this proof as correct?

I feel as though it is correct, however, I'm a little uneasy about the part marked $(**)$. I feel as though I should somehow state or show that $r^{\frac{1}{k}}$ is actually $\in \mathbb{N}$, or is it assumed?

If I'm way off I'd prefer a hint rather than a complete answer.

Comment: Is $k$ fixed or varying? The way you've written $K$, it seems to be the set containing $n^k$ for all natural numbers $n$ and all natural numbers $k$. Your proof however, assumes $k$ is fixed. If that's the case, then your proof is fine.

Comment: $k$ is varying I believe. Would you have any recommendations on improving the proof to account for this variability in $k$? Would my function $f(q)$ be a function of $q$ and $k$ instead? i.e. $f(q,k)$?

Comment: It would depend on what results you know and are able to use. For example, do you know the result which says that if there exists a surjection $f:A\rightarrow B$ then $|A| \ge |B|$?

Comment: I haven't seen that result before, but I can understand what you mean. It's just that we were told to show that if there exists a bijection, $K$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Well, there certainly exists a bijection by virtue of $K$ being countably infinite. But it's going to be a little difficult to explicitly exhibit. That's because the representation $n^k$ is not unique. For example, the number $16$ can be written as $16=2^4 = 4^2$, so the map $(n,k)\mapsto n^k$ is a many-to-one map. I don't think you'll be able to find a simple formula for a bijection. But if you know Cantor's proof of the countability of $\mathbb{Q}$, then you can modify that proof to suit your $K$.

Comment: Why not just construct a bijction?

Comment: @EuYu: I haven't heard of 'Cantor's proof of the countability of $\mathbb{Q}$', unfortunately. Thanks for you help so far, I might just take it up with the tutor if I can't find an alternative.

Comment: Why don't you just show that $K=\mathbb N$ ... (hint: $k=1$)?

Comment: What if I considered the Cartesian product of $n$ and $k$ i.e. $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is one to one with $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Philip yes. But you still have to show that $\mathbb N^2$ maps bijectively into $K$, which is not easy if you neglect that $K=\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any given value of $k,$ the set$\{n^k:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is countably infinite, since $\mathbb{N}$ is countably infinite. Your set $K$ is the union of these individual sets over the various values of $k.$ But a countable union of countably infinite sets is countably infinite (hopefully, you know this result).

Comment: Since the proof I gave holds true for $k$, I can say that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds. This is because we are merely dealing with the intersections of a number of subsets of $K$?. Then after this can expand on what I have by adding something along the lines of "...but a countable union of countably infinite sets is countably infinite, thus $K$ is..."?

Comment: @Philip - Your proof seems fine for a fixed value of $k.$ You should be able to argue as you have indicated to finish it off. I don't know how much detail you require in your proof. You seem to have things under control with what you have done.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the subset $L=\{n^k~:~n\in\mathbb{N},~k=1\}\subseteq K$. Clearly we have $\mathbb{N}=L\subseteq K$. On the other hand we also have $K\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. Thus $K=\mathbb{N}$ and we conclude that $K$ is countable.

Comment: Simple and straight to the point

Comment: @Displayname Thanks!